2D elastic collision between flat disk and rectangular block
I am trying to simulate the elastic collision between a disk and a rectangular body in 2D (like an ideal air hockey table).  I have done the work already for disk-on-disk elastic collisions and documented it here:  https://thecodeofnature.com/.  All I used was conservation of momentum and energy, and changing the frame of reference.
But with a rectangular body involved there will be some conversion of the energy and momentum into their rotational counterparts.  And I'm not sure how to proceed.  To begin with though, I want to consider a stationary disk, and a non-rotating rectangular body which collides with it side-on.  Like this:

After the collision both bodies will have a linear velocity, but the rectangular body will also have an angular velocity.  How do I calculate the final values for the velocity vectors and the angular velocity?  And I don't really understand how angular momentum and energy can be conserved in this system as it seems that they must be zero before the collision and non-zero after!!
Can anyone help??


And I don't really understand how angular momentum and energy can be
conserved in this system as it seems that they must be zero before the
collision and non-zero after!! Can anyone help??

The key idea to resolve this apparent paradox is the notion of what I will call 'notional' angular momentum, which is there even before the collision, even though nothing appears to be spinning. Its circular motion with a varying radius. This Geogebra animation might help demonstrate the relation between linear motion and angular momentum.. Just drag the d slider control or press the video play button at bottom left.
We can pick any point in the reference frame to be the notional centre of rotation of the system. No matter which point we choose to be our centre of rotation, the angular momentum calculated with respect to that point will be the same before and after the collision. In this respect the 'notional' angular momentum is real. I only call it notional because there is no rotational kinetic energy associated with it.
If the rectangle is moving with velocity v without spinning around its own com before the collision, the notional angular velocity of the rectangle before the collision is $\omega = v/r$ where r is the distance of closest approach of the rectangle com, to the notional centre of rotation. The initial notional angular momentum (A) of the rectangle is given by $A = I\omega$ where I is the moment of inertia for the object. A list of formulas for the moment of inertia for various shapes is given here. For a rectangular plate of height h and width w, the moment of spin inertia is given by $m/12 \times (h^2+w^2)$ and this moment is used to calculate the spin of the rectangle about its own com. This is initially zero. The initial orbital moment of inertia is given by $m r^2$  and this gives the initial orbital angular momentum as $I \omega = (m r^2)\times (v/r) = m r v$.
If the object was moving horizontally parallel to the x axis so its y coordinate remains constant then the distance at closest approach (r) is simply the difference in y coordinates of the rectangle com path and the chosen centre of rotation. For convenience it can be arranged that the centre of rotation is on the path of one the objects so that the nominal angular momentum of that object is zero.

As shown in the diagram, the calculation of the perpendicular distance (shown as d) of the path from the cor  is a bit more complicated for diagonal paths.
Another method to calculate the angular momentum before the collision is to measure the distance (d) from the chosen centre of rotation (cor) to the com of the rectangle (distance CJ in the diagram below) at any given instant and use the component of the velocity (v') that is orthogonal to the radial vector and the angular momentum is then given by $\Omega = v'/d$. If the angle of the vector pointing at the com of the rectangle from the chosen point is $\theta$ measured from the horizontal, then $v' = \cos (\theta) d$ and d can be calculated using $d = \Delta X / \sin(\theta)$, where $\Delta X$ is the horizontal distance between the cor and the com of the rectangle. $\Delta X$ is the segment length DJ in the diagram below.

Since this is a elastic collision, the total kinetic energy (linear and rotational) and individually angular and linear momentum are all conserved. While we assign a 'notional' angular momentum to the rectangle even when it appears to moving only in a straight line initially, we do not assign a notional angular kinetic energy to the rectangle before the collision. There is angular kinetic energy after the collision, but his apparent gain in energy is accounted for by the reduction in total linear kinetic energy, so overall the total energy budget is conserved.
After the collision the rectangle will probably be moving slower linearly and this means its orbital angular momentum due to its motion relative to the chosen cor will also be reduced, but since angular momentum is conserved, the rectangle will be spinning around its own com and this spin angular momentum added to the reduced orbital momentum results in the total angular momentum after the collision being the same as before the collision. Don't forget that after the collision there will be rotational kinetic energy due to both the orbital and spin rotations of the rectangle and this is added to the final linear kinetic energies of the rectangle and the circle. All these various forms of linear and rotational energy should add up to the initial linear kinetic energy of the rectangle before the collision.
Energy balance:
Before:
Linear Kinetic energy of the rectangle.
After:
Linear Kinetic energy of the rectangle.
Linear Kinetic energy of the circle.
Orbital angular kinetic energy of the circle.
Spin angular kinetic energy of the circle.
Orbital angular kinetic energy of the rectangle.
Spin angular kinetic energy of the rectangle.
Linear Momentum balance:
Before:
Linear momentum of the rectangle.
After:
Linear momentum of the rectangle.
Linear momentum of the circle.
Angular Momentum balance:
Before:
Orbital angular momentum of the rectangle.
After:
Orbital angular momentum of the rectangle.
Spin angular momentum of the rectangle.
Orbital angular momentum of the circle.
Spin angular momentum of the circle.
All the above assume the circle is initially stationary and in every balance calculation, the sum of all the "after" items should total to the "before" item.

You already know, from your earlier work, and the long algebra you have on your site, that energy and momentum can be conserved.
Angular momentum is also conserved, but it is going to be annoying. You would have a different constant amount of angular momentum for every choice of the axis from which you consider the angular momentum. I mean this: in your black collision picture, you have the ball and the rectangle. If you picked any point on the horizontal line passing through the centre of the ball as the axis, then the initial angular momentum is zero, and the final angular momentum, "made of" the linear momentum of both the ball and rectangle and the angular momentum of the rectangle about its own centre of mass, will be also zero.
But if you picked any axis along the rectangle's centre of mass horizontal line, then the initial angular momentum was never zero. The ball that is moving in a straight line already had angular momentum in the beginning, in this frame of reference.
There are theorems involved that you can work out, that derives the new collision aftermath. It will be much more complicated than the algebraic proof that you had. In fact, you would be very much better placed to derive the solution if you used different variables, the natural ones, that will make the solution drop out as nicely as possible. Or else the algebra will be really annoying.
In this new problem, your code will have to undergo quite a lot of changes. For example, the collision detection is no longer suitable to just be specialised to balls.

Thankyou for the answer, and for taking the time to look at the work I had already done.  I have already solved the problem of detecting collisions between disk and rect. body so no problems there.

I'm not just saying that. I'm trying to point you to solving the new problem yourself, whilst not also giving you the answer outright.

Thanks.  My response above was truncated.  I was going to say: Thankyou ...etc...so no problems there.
Your answer confirms my suspicion that choosing the right frame of reference is crucial to the problem.  In this particular case, what would be the most beneficial frame of reference?  I'm now thinking that it might be the frame of reference travelling along with the centre of mass of the rect.  Then I can calculate the angular momentum of the ball.  But what do you mean by the "natural variables"?

The natural variables in classical mechanics are energy, linear momentum and angular momentum. If you work with velocities, you will keep finding that the equations are very algebraically cumbersome. In fact, you want to try to work in the centre of momentum frame of reference, converting between lab frame, because things are so much simpler there.


you can use those equations
Translation
$$m\,v_m=-\lambda\\
M\,(v_M-u)=\lambda$$
Rotation
$$I\,\omega=\lambda\,\rho$$
and the conservation of the energy
$$m\frac{v_m^2}{2}+ M\frac{v_M^2-u^2}{2}+I\,\frac{\omega^2}{2}=0$$
you obtain 4 equations for 4 unknowns $~v_m~,v_M~,\omega~,\lambda~$
where $~v_m~,v_M~$ are the velocities of the center of mass after collision $~\omega~$ is the angular velocity of rigid body after the collision and $~\lambda=\int F_c\,dt~$ the linear impulse
Notice
adding the translation equations, you obtain the conservation of the momentum.
